# C passing 2d array to a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, matrix

I was given an assignment that required me to write two C functions :

```
1 - Read a matrix from the user.
2 - Write a matrix to the console.
```

Matrix dimensions were not specified, so i can't use something like:

```
void matwrite(float m[3][3]) { ... }
```

is there any work around for this situation?

Comment: Did you read about dynamically allocated arrays in C?

Comment: yes, forgot to mention that i can't use any dynamic allocations.

Comment: `void matwrite(int rows, int cols, float m[rows][cols]) { ... }`

Comment: didn't work here. got error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0.

Comment: `void matwrite(int rows, int cols, float *m)` .. `m[cols*row_index+col_index];`

Comment: @Abdo Ramadan See my answer. It is what you need provided that your compiler supports C99.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It is already clear that Abdo is not using the C99 compiler.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Wjy is it clear?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow My first comment is work fine if he/she is using the C99 compiler. and `C2466`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I am not sure that the error message is related to the unsupporing of VLAs.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Do you not understand that the first example to work in the C99?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow In addition to it, there is a mistake in your code.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What is the mistake?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It is things like can be found at a glance If it is not beginner. There is no bother to get to tell others.

Answer (score -1):

The function signature should be something like:

```
void matwrite(float** m, int w, int h);
```

Then you can iterate over the elements like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < h; ++j) {
    cout << m[i][j] << " "; // For example
  }
  cout << "\n";
}
```

You would call the function with the array and its dimensions, e.g.:

```
float arr[][3] = {
  {1, 2, 3},
  {4, 5, 6},
  {7, 8, 9},
  {1, 2, 3}
};

matwrite(arr, 4, 3);
```

Comment: can you explain how to call this function?
float a[3][3]; matwrite(a); won't work.

Answer (score -1):

You may use Variable Length Arrays in C.

The functions could look like

```
void ReadMatrix( size_t n, float m[][n] );
void WriteMatrix( size_t n, float m[][n] );
```

For example

```
float m[3][3];

ReadMatrix( 3, m );
WriteMatrix( 3, m );
```

If there can be a matrix which is not a square matrix then you need to add one more parameter to the functions. For example

```
void ReadMatrix( size_t m, size_t n, float m[][n] );
void WriteMatrix( size_t m, size_t n, float m[][n] );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ReadMatrix( size_t n, float m[][n] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            scanf( "%f", &m[i][j] );
        }
    }
}

void WriteMatrix( size_t n, float m[][n] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%f ", m[i][j] );
        }
        puts( "" );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    float m[3][3];

    ReadMatrix( 3, m );
    WriteMatrix( 3, m );

    return 0;
}
```